# git init doesn't execute hooks

Tags: git, init, githooks, ctags

I am following the steps outlined in the below link to ensure that my hooks are rerun every time upon `git init`:

[Getting started with Ctags with Vim and Git.](https://geekdude.github.io/tech/ctags/)

Since I don't have `fish` installed, I replaced the function `git-reload-hooks-all.fish` in the link with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -rp "Enter repo: " repo
cd "$repo/.git/hooks" || exit
rm -fv ./*
cp ~/.git_template/hooks/* .
cd "$GITWORKSPACE/$repo" || exit
git init
```

`$GITWORKSPACE` in my set up points to the top-level directory that contains all the individual git repositories.

When I execute the script for a chosen git repository under `$GITWORKSPACE`, it runs successfully and I can see the following message printed on the terminal:

```
Reinitialized existing git repository in $GITWORKSPACE/$repo/.git
```

Note that the variables are replaced by the actual paths in the above output.

I can also see that `./git/hooks/` folder has been updated with the hooks I want.

However, the `ctags` hook outlined in the link above has not been run, and I cannot see any `.tag` file under `$GITWORKSPACE/$repo/` path.

Can someone tell me why git init fails to rerun the hooks?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the tutorial says, `ctags` is called in the hooks `post-checkout`, `post-commit`, `post-merge`, `post-rewrite`.

```
#!/bin/sh

dir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)
$dir/hooks/ctags >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

`git init` does not invoke any of these hooks. As the hook names suggest, they are invoked by other commands. And, `post` indicates it runs after the command finishes. The `post` family cannot affect the exit code of the command. For example, `post-checkout` is invoked by `git checkout` or `git switch`. You can find the details in [githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

You can try `git checkout`, `git commit`, `git merge` and `git rebase` to test if `ctags` runs as expected.